# Linq to Entities returning all outer entities and one or none associated entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

I'm using LinqPad with and Entity Framework 4 model and MS SQL 2008 database.

Suppose we have a Customer entity that has an association to Purchase with a foreign key to Customer.CustomerID.

The following linq produces an `ObjectQuery<Customer>` with `Purchases` association of `EntityCollection<Purchase>`.

```
from c in Customers.Include("Purchases")
select c
```

Now I want to get *all* customers with only the most recent purchase. If there is no purchase then I want the `Purchases` collection to be empty.

I need something like the following, but that maintains the entity and association. I want to get *all* the customers with a collection limited to 0 or 1 purchases.

```
from c in Customers
from p in c.Purchases.Where(p => p.PurchaseDate == c.Purchases.Max(m => m.PurchaseDate).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { CustomerID = c.CustomerID, PurchaseID = (int?)p.PurchaseID }
```

In my service I return a `List<Customer>`, so I think I need to maintain the `Customer` entity and `Purchases` association in the return from the linq query.

Use case:

```
var customers = CustomerService.GetCustomersAndMostRecentOrder();
foreach (Customer c in customers) {
    Console.WriteLine(c.Lastname + ":" + 
                     c.Purchases.Count() == 0 ? "None" : c.Purchases[0].PurchaseOrder);
}
```

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do part of the query with linq-to-entities and than the rest with linq-to-objects like so:

```
var query = (from c in Customers
             select new 
             { 
               Customer = c, 
               Purchase = c.Purchases.OrderByDescending(p => p.PurchaseDate).FirstOrDefault()
             })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(c => new Customer()
                         {
                           CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                           CustomerProperty2 = c.CustomerProperty2,
                           CustomerProperty3 = c.CustomerProperty3,
                           ...,
                           Purchases = new Purchase[] { c.Purchase }
                         } 
                    );
```

Comment: I tried this, but am getting 0 purchases in the output. -- Added `as EntityCollection<Purchase>` on `Purchases = c.Purchases`

Comment: Try changing Take(1) to FirstOrDefault()

Comment: No that changes it back to an instance of Purchase not a collection of Purchases. Also tried DefaultIfEmpty()... get 0 Purchases.

Comment: Look at the complete answer, with linq-to-objects in the last line there is: Purchases = new Purchase[] { c.Purchase }

Comment: "Cannot implicity convert type `...Purchase[]` to `...EntityCollection<Purchase>`" Sorry I know you're right, I just keep fighting the syntax, which probably means I'm doing the wrong thing.